# Need help incorporating randoms in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to get my sprites on random positions on the screen but it says "CGFloat is not convertible to Double"

```
var randomNumber = arc4random()

bat1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rsz_silverbat.png")
bat1.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * 0.1, y: self.frame.size.height * randomNumber)
```

Comment: We're not debuggers here. The message is sufficient to guide you in making an attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
bat1.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(0.1), y: self.view.frame.size.height * CGFloat(randomNumber))
```